# Is it Possible to give Flex Canvas editable=false?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml

Actually my intention is In Flex Application have 10 text input box.

So i'm doing Create Canvas and Place all text inputs into that canvas then i'm define

```
canvasId.editable=false;
```

But it is giving error !! i know there is no editable in Canvas...

But it is Possible?

Comment: Only if you create a custom component. By default there's nothing editable about a Canvas: it's just a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with states. Create two states:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="stateEditable"/>
    <s:State name="stateReadOnly"/>
</s:states>
```

And for each textInput:

```
<s:TextInput editable.stateReadOnly="false"/>
```

Then in actionscript:

```
currentState = "stateReadOnly";
```

Answer (score 1):

Give 'editable' property to your textinput